# How to animate CCSprite in Cocos2D 3.x?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

do you know how to animate a `CCSprite` in the new **Cocos2D v3.x** ?

A lot of classes are changed, and old method seems not work.

```
NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sprite-%d.png",i]];
        [animFrames addObject:frame];
    }
    CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithName:@"run" delay:0.1f frames:animFrames];
    [mySprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation restoreOriginalFrame:NO]]];
```

any idea?

thanks.

---

#### extra info

[image]

Comment: all action classes now begin with CCAction...

Comment: @LearnCocos2D have you a simple example, please?

Comment: the classes were just renamed, no need for an example

Comment: Patience. I'm not capable.

Comment: Just start typing CCActionR.. and Xcode will make autocomplete suggestions. ;)

Comment: the problem is't not CCAction prefix, but for example `animationWithName` that won't work.

Comment: "won't work" means what exactly? You could set a breakpoint and step into the method to understand what the code behind the scene does. If it's not compiling refer to the autocomplete suggestions or browse to the class interface to see which methods it offers. Unfortunalety this class is currently missing from the api reference. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/

Comment: sorry, `animationWithName` doesn't exist! how to solve?

Comment: look in the code for that class, use xcode search if need be, the method in question is now animationWithSpriteFrames https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v3/cocos2d/CCAnimation.h#L155

Comment: Nothing to do. I rollback to version 2. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how it works:

```
    NSMutableArray *animationFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(int i = 1; i <= FRAMES; ++i)
    {
        CCSpriteFrame *spriteFrame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"animationFrame%d.png", i]]; //
    }

    //Create an animation from the set of frames you created earlier
    CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames: animationFrames delay:delay];

    //Create an action with the animation that can then be assigned to a sprite
    CCActionAnimate *animationAction = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];

    CCActionRepeatForever *repeatingAnimation = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:animationAction];
    [self runAction:repeatingAnimation];
```

Comment: Did you `#import` Cocos2d into the class where you are trying to perform the animation? You can download this: https://github.com/MakeGamesWithUs/CCAnimatedSprite it is a working implementation and should allow you to find out the differences.

Comment: Just for future reference if importing cocos2d doesn't the problem import `#import "CCAnimation.h"` it worked for me

Comment: I'm getting nil values in spriteFrame for loop. Anyone know how to change this?

Comment: You forgot to write [animationFrames addObject:spriteFrame]; in the loop

Answer (score 1):

You could change `CCRepeatForever` to `CCActionRepeatForever`.