# Sprite Frame Animation Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I've been trying to make an animated sprite, they're are a lot of tutorials but they're all for Cocos2d 2.x. My sprite sheet is named flappbird.png and the .plist is named flappbird.plist

I have this code but every time i start the scene it just crashes, this is in my **init** method

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

_player = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"monster1.png"]; // comes from your .plist file
_player.position  = ccp(self.contentSize.width/28,self.contentSize.height/2);
_player.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, _player.contentSize} cornerRadius:0]; // 1
_player.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"playerGroup";
_player.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"monster1.png"];
[batchNode addChild:_player];
[self addChild:batchNode];

NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"flapbird%d.png",i]];
    [animFrames addObject:frame];
}

CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames delay:0.2f];
[_player runAction:[CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]]];

[_physicsWorld addChild:_player];

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to animate CCSprite in Cocos2D 3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645953/how-to-animate-ccsprite-in-cocos2d-3-x)

Comment: See i tried implementing the answer of that question to min but it would crash and nothing would happen

Comment: what does it tell you when it crashes?

Comment: `2014-02-17 16:13:09.875 Bye Flappy[53793:70b] -[CCFileUtils fullPathForFilename:contentScale:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found: monster1.png` I think the problem is that my .plist isnt linked. But how would i link it? The monster1.png is defined inside my flappbird.plist @connor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Animate sprite with spritesheet in Cocos2d 3.0

Make sure to add `#import "CCAnimation.h"` at the beginning of your code

Also add the sprite sheet after the self.userInteractionEnabled = YES; in the init

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"your.plist"];
```

No add all this where the sprite will be

```
//The sprite animation
NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i <= 7; ++i)
{
     [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"monster%d.png", i]]];
}
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation
                         animationWithSpriteFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f]; //Speed in which the frames will go at

//Adding png to sprite
monstertest = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"monster1.png"];

//Positioning the sprite
monstertest.position  = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2,self.contentSize.height/2);

//Repeating the sprite animation
CCActionAnimate *animationAction = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim];
CCActionRepeatForever *repeatingAnimation = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:animationAction];

//Animation continuously repeating
[monstertest runAction:repeatingAnimation];

//Adding the Sprite to the Scene
[self addChild:monstertest];
```

Hope this helps somebody :D Cheers

Comment: If you've already added all of the frames to the cache as part of the [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:] call, then the line: monstertest = [...]; could read monstertest = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:] and pass in the name of the first frame.  This way the sprite's initial image is pulled from the cache instead of loading it into memory from the .png separately.

Comment: @PKCLsoft That was in the previous version. In 3.x they both use spriteWithImageNamed and the way it works is that if it exists in the cache then the cache will be used.

Comment: @agro1986 thanks, I missed that crucial piece of info.