# Cocos2d v3.0 - Sprite animation from spritesheet

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How to use SpriteAnimation in Cocos2d v3 ?

Below code helped in cocos2d 2.0, now getting many error like  CCAnimationCache, CCAnimate  not found. Is there any cocos2d 3.0 sample which uses sprite frames for animation ?

```
    NSString *animName = @"FOG_ANIMATION";
    CCAnimation* animation = nil;

    animation = [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache]  animationByName:animName];

    if(!animation)
    {
        NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        CCSpriteFrameCache *cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

        for(int i=1;i<=18;i++)
        {
            NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Steam_%.2d.png",i];
            CCSpriteFrame *frame = [cache spriteFrameByName:file];

            if(frame)
            {
                [animFrames addObject:frame];
            }
        }

        animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames];
        animation.delayPerUnit = DELAY_PER_FRAME_HERO_RUN;// 0.1f;
        animation.restoreOriginalFrame = NO;

        [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] addAnimation:animation name:animName];
    }


    CCAnimate *AnimAction  = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
    CCRepeatForever *repAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:AnimAction];

    [steam runAction:repAction];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CCAnimationCache  in Cocos2d v3 also:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "cocos2d-ui.h"
#import "CCAnimation.h"
#import "CCAnimationCache.h"

-(void)animateBird
{
    NSString *animName = @"Bird_ANIM";

    CCAnimation* animation = nil;

    animation = [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache]  animationByName:animName];

    if(!animation)
    {
        NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

        for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
        {
            NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hero_01_Flap_%.2d.png",i];
            CCSpriteFrame *frame = [cache spriteFrameByName:file];

            if(frame)
            {
                [animFrames addObject:frame];
            }
        }

        animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames];

        animation.delayPerUnit = 0.13f;// 0.1f;
        animation.restoreOriginalFrame = NO;

        [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] addAnimation:animation name:animName];
    }

    CCActionAnimate *AnimAction  = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
    CCActionRepeatForever *repAction = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:AnimAction];

    [bird runAction:repAction];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link, It shows how to make a spriteframe animation, hope this helps :D

[Sprite Frame Animation Cocos2d 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841265/sprite-frame-animation-cocos2d-3-0/21843802#21843802)