# Create animated sprites with preloaded images

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a lot of images that I want to preload and use in a sprite animation:

I'm preloading the images like this:

```
NSArray *imageHeroMenus = @[
                            @"hero_menu0001.png", //0
                            @"hero_menu0002.png", //0
                           ...
                            @"hero_menu0120.png", //0
                            ];

for (NSString *imageHero in imageHeroMenus)
    {


        CCTexture * tex = [CCTexture textureWithFile:imageHero];
        [loadedHeroMenu addObject:tex];


    }
```

How can I use this imageHeroMenus to create an animated sprite?

Because when I load a static sprite, I use this code:

```
background3 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[loadedTextures objectAtIndex:0]];
```

With objectAtIndex at the index that I want of the array. But I don't know how to adapt it to a animated sprite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand you use cocos2d v3.0? If yes - try to use fore example a solution presented here:
[Sprite Frame Animation Cocos2d 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841265/sprite-frame-animation-cocos2d-3-0/21843802#21843802). Hope it helps - i think the approach by using SpriteFrames described in the link is a good one. Also - it would be easier to name your files in way:

```
 "hero_menu1.png, hero_menu2.png,... hero_menu11.png,..."
```

rather than:

```
"hero_menu0001.png, hero_menu0002.png,... hero_menu0011.png,..."
```

since then in code you can load all files in a simple for:
    NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 120; i++)
    {
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hero_menu%d.png",i]];
        [animFrames addObject:frame];
    }

and the use them in CCAnimation (see the link above).

---

If you want to use CCTexture You can use

```
(void) addSpriteFrameWithTexture:(CCTexture*)texture rect:(CGRect)rect;
```

method (see CCAnimation.h) to add animation frames with your uploaded textures (for example in a for loop, instead of using animationWithSpriteFrames explained in the example I mention before.