# try to create CCSpriteFrame but get nil values

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to animate a CCSprite in cocos2d v3 following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645953/how-to-animate-ccsprite-in-cocos2d-3-x), but I'm getting the following error message in Log:

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
 insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

This is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *animationFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    int frameCount = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        CCSpriteFrame *spriteFrame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hero-%d.png", i]];

            [animationFrames addObject:spriteFrame]; //ERROR OCCUR THIS LINE

        frameCount++;
        if (frameCount == 8) break;
    }
```

The problem is that all spriteFrames are nil, but I don't why. I already tested the i values with NSLog, and also tried to add hero-1.png to a CCSprite object and works fine. I also tried to add all fixed hero-1.png in all frames to verify if the problem was with i variable. But didn't work also.

Comment: Did you load the sprite frames before running this code?

Comment: What do you mean with load the sprite frames?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349388/cocos2d-sprite-repeat-animation-forever/19373921#19373921